# "framework not found" when compiling C++ program on Mac OS-X

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, cmake, ogre3d

I definitely need some help with this problem. I'm trying to fix this since 5 days and as I tried almost every single idea I was able to find on the Internet, I'm going crazy...

When I compile my C++ project with the makefile generated by Cmake the code compile up to 100% but then is unable to link the OGRE framework and exit with an **Error 1**.

As I was unable to compile using my own project and as the framework my program is unable to locate is the OGRE framework, I tried with the [files](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre+Wiki+Tutorial+Framework#Quick_Download) provided with the Ogre3D setup [tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Mac+OSX) to simplify the problem to it's maximum. But the problem and the error remain exactly the sames, and the compilation process stop with:

> ld: **framework not found** OGRE

I tried to copy the **Ogre.framework** found in **OgreSDK/lib/release** in the default /Library/Framework of the system and almost everywhere on this computer including the project folder (with modification on the OgreFindFrameWork.cmake file) and particularly all the folder targeted by the OgreFindFrameWork.cmake file, but this error is still here.

I also tried a lot of Cmake modifications or to compile using Xcode, but as it always finish with the same error message, I decided to use the simplest one to illustrate this question. So the following informations are relatives to the OGRETutorialFramework debug project pointed above.

Does anyone can explain me what I need to change to make the linker able to locate a defined framework (I guess that this is not a problem specific to the Ogre framework and I would probably have the same error with another framework) ?

Thank you.

Index of the following parts:
- 1/ The *make* log
- 2/ The CMakeFile.txt of OGRETutorialFramework
- 3/ The versions of the softs used

---

- **1/ The make generating and building log**

Here is the log of the generating process:

```
Valkeas-Mac:OGRETutorialFramework root# make
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Detected g++ 4.0.1

-- Enabling GCC visibility flags
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- OGRE_PREFIX_WATCH changed.
-- Found Ogre Cthugha (1.7.3)
-- Found OGRE: -framework OGRE
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: -framework OGRE
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: /Volumes/Data/OgreSDK/lib/libOgreTerrain.dylib
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: /Volumes/Data/OgreSDK/lib/libOgreProperty.dylib
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: /Volumes/Data/OgreSDK/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.dylib
-- Looking for OIS...
-- Found OIS: /Volumes/Data/OgreSDK/lib/release/libOIS.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

As you can see the framework is found (**-- Found OGRE: -framework OGRE**).

And here is the log of the building process:

```
-- Build files have been written to: /var/root/Desktop/OGRETutorialFramework
Scanning dependencies of target OGRETutorialFramework
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/OGRETutorialFramework.dir/BaseApplication.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/OGRETutorialFramework.dir/TutorialApplication.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable OGRETutorialFramework.app/Contents/MacOS/OGRETutorialFramework
ld: framework not found OGRE
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [OGRETutorialFramework.app/Contents/MacOS/OGRETutorialFramework] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OGRETutorialFramework.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Valkeas-Mac:OGRETutorialFramework root#
```

And as you can see it is unable to find the OGRE framework (**ld: framework not found OGRE**)

---

- **2/ The CMakeFile.txt of OGRETutorialFramework debug project**

My **Ogre SDK** is on my second hard-drive called "Data" so I use the path: **/Volumes/Data/OgreSDK**

Here is my current CMakeList.txt (the one provided on the Ogre Setting Up tutorial slightly modified to match my folder paths) for the OGRETutorialFramework.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
set(CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS TRUE)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)

set(OGRE_HOME "/Volumes/Data/OgreSDK")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "${OGRE_HOME}/boost_1_46_1")

# Use relative paths
# This is mostly to reduce path size for command-line limits on windows
if(WIN32)
  # This seems to break Xcode projects so definitely don't enable on Apple builds
  set(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS true)
  set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${OGRE_HOME}/CMake/;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
  set(OGRE_SAMPLES_INCLUDEPATH
      ${OGRE_HOME}/Samples/include)
endif()

# Assign compiler for Mac OS X-based systems
# NOTE: This logic is order-dependent and must occur here because the
# configuration phase of CMake projects will fall into an infinite loop
# if compiler assignments are modified after issuing a project(...) command.
#
if (OGRE_BUILD_PLATFORM_IPHONE)
  # Force gcc <= 4.2 on iPhone
  include(CMakeForceCompiler)
  CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(gcc-4.2 GNU)
  CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(gcc-4.2 GNU)
elseif (APPLE AND NOT OGRE_BUILD_PLATFORM_IPHONE)
  # Force gcc <= 4.0 on Mac OS X because 4.2 is not supported prior to Mac OS X 10.5
  include(CMakeForceCompiler)
  CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(gcc-4.0 GNU)
  CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(gcc-4.0 GNU)
endif ()

set(OGRE_PROJECT_NAME
  "OGRETutorialFramework"
)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin")

project(${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME})

# Include necessary submodules
# set(OGRE_SOURCE_DIR "/Applications/OgreSDK")
set(OGRE_SOURCE_DIR "/Volumes/Data/OgreSDK")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 
  "${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake"
  "${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Utils" 
  "${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Packages"
)
set(OGRE_SAMPLES_INCLUDEPATH
  "${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/Samples/Common/include"
)
include(CMakeDependentOption)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
include(MacroLogFeature)
include(OgreConfigTargets)
include(PreprocessorUtils)
set(OGRE_TEMPLATES_DIR "${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Templates")


#####################################################################
# Set up the basic build environment
#####################################################################

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
  # CMake defaults to leaving CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE empty. This screws up
  # differentiation between debug and release builds.
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: None (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel." FORCE)
endif ()

if (NOT APPLE)
  # Create debug libraries with _d postfix
  set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")
endif ()

# Set compiler specific build flags
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  check_cxx_compiler_flag(-msse OGRE_GCC_HAS_SSE)
  if (OGRE_GCC_HAS_SSE)
    add_definitions(-msse)
  endif ()
endif ()
if (MSVC)
  if (CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL STREQUAL "nmake")
    # set variable to state that we are using nmake makefiles
   set(NMAKE TRUE)
  endif ()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /fp:fast")
  # Enable intrinsics on MSVC in debug mode
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /Oi")
  if (CMAKE_CL_64)
    # Visual Studio bails out on debug builds in 64bit mode unless
   # this flag is set...
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /bigobj")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} /bigobj")
  endif ()
endif ()
if (MINGW)
  add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500)
endif ()

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT MINGW)
  # Test for GCC visibility
  include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
  check_cxx_compiler_flag(-fvisibility=hidden OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY)
  if (OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY)
    # determine gcc version
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion 
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE OGRE_GCC_VERSION)
    message(STATUS "Detected g++ ${OGRE_GCC_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS "Enabling GCC visibility flags")
    set(OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY_FLAGS "-DOGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY -fvisibility=hidden")

    # check if we can safely add -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
    string(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" OGRE_BUILD_TYPE)
    if (OGRE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "debug" AND OGRE_GCC_VERSION VERSION_LESS "4.2")
      message(STATUS "Skipping -fvisibility-inlines-hidden due to possible bug in g++ < 4.2")
    else ()
      set(OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY_FLAGS "${OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY_FLAGS} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")
    endif ()
  endif (OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY)

  # Fix x64 issues on Linux
  if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" STREQUAL "x86_64" AND NOT APPLE)
    add_definitions(-fPIC)
  endif()  
endif (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX AND NOT MINGW)

# determine system endianess
#include(TestBigEndian)
#test_big_endian(OGRE_TEST_BIG_ENDIAN)
set(OGRE_TEST_BIG_ENDIAN FALSE)

# Add OgreMain include path
include_directories("${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/OgreMain/include")
include_directories("${OGRE_BINARY_DIR}/include")
if (APPLE)
  if (OGRE_BUILD_PLATFORM_IPHONE)
    include_directories("${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/OgreMain/include/iPhone")

    # Set static early for proper dependency detection
    set(OGRE_STATIC TRUE)
  else ()
    include_directories("${OGRE_SOURCE_DIR}/OgreMain/include/OSX")
  endif ()
endif (APPLE)


find_package(OGRE REQUIRED)

if(NOT "${OGRE_VERSION_NAME}" STREQUAL "Cthugha")
  message(SEND_ERROR "You need Ogre 1.7 Cthugha to build this.")
endif()

find_package(OIS REQUIRED)

if(NOT OIS_FOUND)
   message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find OIS.")
endif()

# Find Boost
if (NOT OGRE_BUILD_PLATFORM_IPHONE)
   if (WIN32 OR APPLE)
      set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
   else ()
      # Statically linking boost to a dynamic Ogre build doesn't work on Linux 64bit
      set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ${OGRE_STATIC})
   endif ()
   if (MINGW)
      # this is probably a bug in CMake: the boost find module tries to look for
      # boost libraries with name libboost_*, but CMake already prefixes library
      # search names with "lib". This is the workaround.
      set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES} "")
   endif ()
   set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.42" "1.42.0" "1.41.0" "1.41" "1.40.0" "1.40" "1.39.0" "1.39" "1.38.0" "1.38" "1.37.0" "1.37" )
   # Components that need linking (NB does not include header-only components like bind)
   set(OGRE_BOOST_COMPONENTS thread date_time)
   find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${OGRE_BOOST_COMPONENTS} QUIET)
   if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
      # Try again with the other type of libs
      set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS NOT ${Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS})
      find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${OGRE_BOOST_COMPONENTS} QUIET)
   endif()
   find_package(Boost QUIET)

   # Set up referencing of Boost
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
   add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
   set(OGRE_LIBRARIES ${OGRE_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()

set(HDRS
   ./BaseApplication.h
   ./TutorialApplication.h
)

set(SRCS
   ./BaseApplication.cpp
   ./TutorialApplication.cpp
)

include_directories( ${OIS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   ${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   ${OGRE_SAMPLES_INCLUDEPATH}
)

add_executable(${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${HDRS} ${SRCS})

set_target_properties(${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)

target_link_libraries(${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} ${OGRE_LIBRARIES} ${OIS_LIBRARIES})

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dist/bin)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dist/media)

# post-build copy for win32
if(WIN32 AND NOT MINGW)
   add_custom_command( TARGET ${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
      COMMAND if not exist .\\dist\\bin mkdir .\\dist\\bin )
   add_custom_command( TARGET ${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
      COMMAND copy \"$(TargetPath)\" .\\dist\\bin )
endif(WIN32 AND NOT MINGW)
if(MINGW)
   set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/dist/bin)
endif(MINGW)

if(WIN32)

   install(TARGETS ${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME}
      RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
      CONFIGURATIONS All)

   install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/Media
      DESTINATION ./
      CONFIGURATIONS Release RelWithDebInfo Debug
   )

   install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/bin/plugins.cfg
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/bin/resources.cfg
      DESTINATION bin
      CONFIGURATIONS Release RelWithDebInfo
   )

   install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/bin/plugins_d.cfg
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/bin/resources_d.cfg
      DESTINATION bin
      CONFIGURATIONS Debug
   )

   install(FILES ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_REL}/OgreMain.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_REL}/RenderSystem_Direct3D9.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_REL}/RenderSystem_GL.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_REL}/OIS.dll
      DESTINATION bin
      CONFIGURATIONS Release RelWithDebInfo
   )

   install(FILES ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_DBG}/OgreMain_d.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_DBG}/RenderSystem_Direct3D9_d.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_DBG}/RenderSystem_GL_d.dll
      ${OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR_DBG}/OIS_d.dll
      DESTINATION bin
      CONFIGURATIONS Debug
   )
endif(WIN32)

set_property(TARGET ${OGRE_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
```

---

- **3/ The versions of the softs used**

OSX version: **10.6.7** (Snow Leopard)
Xcode version:**3.2.6**
GCC version: **4.6** (4.5.3 doesn't compile to 100%, and older versions do not support C++0x which I need)
Ogre version: **1.7.3**
Cmake version: **2.8.3** or 2.8.4 (I tried both)

Comment: would you try and exec the command: `lipo -info <ogre.executable>`, where ogre.executable is the executable file you find in `OGRE.framework/Versions/Current/...`

Comment: it returns: `Architectures in the fat files: Ogre are: i386 x86_64`

Comment: Hum it seems fixed. I'm not sure how I did that through, I need to sleep a bit before posting the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you have a problem with duplicated Frameworks in SDK path. You need to move your Frameworks from

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Frameworks
```

to

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks
```

and then repair the symbolic link `/Library/Frameworks`.

I found the solution at [Re[2]: не могу въехать в ошибку линковки](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp.applied/4532152.1.aspx):

> If you are interested: The XCode gets standart library
> (`libstdc++-static.a`) depends from the current SDK configuration. But
> `libstdc++-static.a` library from MacOS10.5.sdk configuration do not
> contain `_M_insert`, `_M_extract` symbols. For fix this problem we need
> just switch to the MacOSX10.6.sdk.
>
> BTW!!! If you are use XCode 3.2.6 you will encounter with surprise
> (bug) from Apple!
>
> The folder: `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library` contain the folder
> `Frameworks` with link `Frameworks` inside. i.e.:
> `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Frameworks` This is
> wrong.
>
> If you will try to install and use third-party frameworks (for example
> CG.Frameworks), XCode doesn't find these framework. Because
> `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library` must contain link to the
> `Frameworks` folder BUT not the `Framework` folder.
>
> Fortunately this problem easy to fix. You need just need rename the
> `Frameworks` to (for example) `_Framework`. Then copy alias `Framework` from
> the `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/_Frameworks/Frameworks` to
> `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/` and then remove renamed folder
> `_Frameworks` forewer.
>
> I repeat again this applies only for XCode 3.2.6

Answer (score 3):

It is highly possible that when you execute make, and it fails, you can find the exact output of the compiler in a log file (or other kind of mechanism). Even more important is knowing the exact command line that was executed for linking and that failed (that you could also find in the log file).

Inspecting the way the linker was called could provide an explanation for what is going wrong and possibly a way to fix the problem and make it link.

If you can't find a log file, then possibly you can find a way for the make output to be more verbose and show all the compiler/linker invocations with all their parameters.

If you find that and post it here, we can inspect it together and maybe find a clue.

The same would be feasible if you go back to your Xcode project and in the Build Results window click on the icon left of the error message to display the command line and output.

Comment: I must apologize because I was placing the framework in the wrong Library folder (as a new OS-X user I wasn't aware they were multiple Library folders, and obviously the one I place the Ogre.framework wasn't the main Library folder).

Comment: I don't know if I should accept this answer... This was not the solution (100% my own fault), but the advice is a good one and you were support full. So it worth at least a +1